# Excel: Changing date formats

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a date that is formatted like this:

`5/31/2016 13:00` in A1, and I want it to match with a date formatted like this:

`5/31` (resulting from `TODAY()-7`) in B1. How can it return TRUE if I match A1 and B1 in C1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C1:

```
=INT(A1)=INT(B1)
```

Dates are the whole number part of a number.  Time is the decimal.  So we need to compare just the whole numbers.

Comment: WHY YOU POST ANSWER =P

Comment: @findwindow Somebody I respect told me to.